# PeerJS Multiple Connection

Tags: webrtc, peerjs

I am working on creating a group video chat using WebRTC and PeerJS.  I have been trying to connect to multiple peer id so that when a user join the call room, they can see other immediately.]

I have to call each user when the entering the room.

My code is:

```
const socket = useSocket();
  const [remoteSocketId, setRemoteSocketId] = useState(null);
  const [myStream, setMyStream] = useState();
  const [remoteStream, setRemoteStream] = useState();

  const handleUserJoined = useCallback(({ email, id }) => {
    console.log(`Email ${email} joined room`);
    setRemoteSocketId(id);
  }, []);

  const handleCallUser = useCallback(async () => {
    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
      audio: true,
      video: true,
    });
    const offer = await peer.getOffer();
    socket.emit("user:call", { to: remoteSocketId, offer });
    setMyStream(stream);
  }, [remoteSocketId, socket]);

  const handleIncomingCall = useCallback(
    async ({ from, offer }) => {
      setRemoteSocketId(from);
      const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        audio: true,
        video: true,
      });
      setMyStream(stream);
      console.log(`Incoming Call`, from, offer);
      const ans = await peer.getAnswer(offer);
      socket.emit("call:accepted", { to: from, ans });
    },
    [socket]
  );

  const sendStreams = useCallback(() => {
    for (const track of myStream.getTracks()) {
      peer.peer.addTrack(track, myStream);
    }
  }, [myStream]);

  const handleCallAccepted = useCallback(
    ({ from, ans }) => {
      peer.setLocalDescription(ans);
      console.log("Call Accepted!");
      sendStreams();
    },
    [sendStreams]
  );

  const handleNegoNeeded = useCallback(async () => {
    const offer = await peer.getOffer();
    socket.emit("peer:nego:needed", { offer, to: remoteSocketId });
  }, [remoteSocketId, socket]);

  useEffect(() => {
    peer.peer.addEventListener("negotiationneeded", handleNegoNeeded);
    return () => {
      peer.peer.removeEventListener("negotiationneeded", handleNegoNeeded);
    };
  }, [handleNegoNeeded]);

  const handleNegoNeedIncoming = useCallback(
    async ({ from, offer }) => {
      const ans = await peer.getAnswer(offer);
      socket.emit("peer:nego:done", { to: from, ans });
    },
    [socket]
  );

  const handleNegoNeedFinal = useCallback(async ({ ans }) => {
    await peer.setLocalDescription(ans);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    handleCallUser();
  }, [handleCallUser]);  

  useEffect(() => {
    peer.peer.addEventListener("track", async (ev) => {
      const remoteStream = ev.streams;
      console.log("GOT TRACKS!!");
      setRemoteStream(remoteStream[0]);
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("user:joined", handleUserJoined);
    socket.on("incoming:call", handleIncomingCall);
    socket.on("call:accepted", handleCallAccepted);
    socket.on("peer:nego:needed", handleNegoNeedIncoming);
    socket.on("peer:nego:final", handleNegoNeedFinal);

    return () => {
      socket.off("user:joined", handleUserJoined);
      socket.off("incoming:call", handleIncomingCall);
      socket.off("call:accepted", handleCallAccepted);
      socket.off("peer:nego:needed", handleNegoNeedIncoming);
      socket.off("peer:nego:final", handleNegoNeedFinal);
    };
  }, [
    socket,
    handleUserJoined,
    handleIncomingCall,
    handleCallAccepted,
    handleNegoNeedIncoming,
    handleNegoNeedFinal,
  ]);
```

But it didn't produce the result.

Any tip? Thanks.